# How to color the selected portion of the diagonal line of scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to select points within diagonal line, but if you look at the plot, it is also selecting points below the diagonal line.

```
IBD$COLOR <- ifelse((IBD$Z0 < 0.5 &
                       IBD$Z0 > 0.10 &
                       IBD$Z1 < 0.9 &
                       IBD$Z1 > 0.5), "OK", "BAD")
```

I want to plot the points in blue without selecting the points below the diagonal line. What would be the proper way to select `IBD$COLOR` here?

```
ggplot(IBD, aes(x=Z0, y=Z1))+ geom_point(aes(color=COLOR)) + ggtitle("Replication dataset - 2441")
```

[image]

Comment: `aes(color=Z0 == Z1)` for being exactly on the diagonal and `aes(color = abs(Z0 - Z1) < 0.01)` for points up to some distance (0.01) from the diagonal seems like would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're suggesting there should be three colors: blue/red for ok/bad, and perhaps gray for dots not on or near the diagonal. For that, I suggest your `ifelse` should be a bit more complex to incorporate "distance" from the diagonal as well.

Here's some fake data to mimic your plot:

```r
## generate fake data
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Z0=runif(10000), Z1=runif(10000))
dat <- dat[(dat$Z0 + dat$Z1) < 1,]

## your processing picks up here
dat$COLOR <- with(dat, ifelse((Z1 + Z0) < 0.95, "Boring",
                              ifelse(0.1 < Z0 & Z0 < 0.5 & 0.5 < Z1 & Z1 < 0.9, "OK", "Bad")))
ggplot(dat, aes(Z0, Z1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = COLOR)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Boring="gray", OK="blue", Bad="red"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with colors on the diagonal, gray off of the diagonal]

If you want to control the order of the `COLOR` legend (it will be sorted alphabetically by default), then you will need to use `factor`s, perhaps

```r
dat$COLOR <- factor(dat$COLOR, levels = c("OK", "Bad", "Boring"))
```

before plotting.

If you're using `dplyr`, it may be simpler to use `case_when` to manage the processing (and factorizing), perhaps:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    COLOR = case_when(
      (Z1 + Z0) < 0.95 ~ "Boring",
      between(Z0, 0.1, 0.5) & between(Z1, 0.5, 0.9) ~ "OK",
      TRUE ~ "Bad"),
    COLOR = factor(COLOR, levels = c("OK", "Bad", "Boring"))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Z0, Z1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = COLOR)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Boring="gray", OK="blue", Bad="red"))
```

incorporating both the ease of `between(.)` and `case_when`. (Note that `between` uses *closed* ends, so this is actually equivalent to `0.1 <= Z0 & Z0 <= 0.5`, etc.)